# java- can anyone tell me why this image wont load?

Tags: java, swing

I am using netbeans and am trying to load an image from my disk.  the program is not giving me any errors, but the frame is not popping up. ?  I tried using the other label with just text in it and it works just fine.  I dont think there is anything wrong with my method for calling the image, it's just that for some reason the frame won't show?

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.imageio.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Play {

    /**
     * @param args
     *            the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("window");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JLabel emptyLabel = new JLabel("yo");
        BufferedImage img = null;
        try {
            img = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Users\\anon\\Desktop\\alien.png"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }

        emptyLabel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(175, 100));
        frame.getContentPane().add(img, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: Consider printing exception massage instead of ignoring exception. Add `e.printStackTrace()` in your catch block.

Comment: How do you know there's nothing wrong? You're explicitly ignoring any exception thrown.

Comment: You also need FORWARD-SLASHES "C:/../.../.../.     Not backward ones

Comment: @NullSoulException Why? Both `/` and ``\\`` will be interpreted the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this even compile?

```
frame.getContentPane().add(img, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

You are trying add a BufferedImage to a JPanel.  You are probably intending to create a JPanel and "add" the image with something like this...

```
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, this);        
}
```

Comment: +1 or just set the image as an ImageIcon to the label and add the label. `emptyLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img)); frame.add(emptyLabel);`

Comment: What's wrong with a JLabel? Also, you should be passing this as the ImageObserver parameter to drawImage

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thanks, I added the ImageObserver.  (I'm guilty of setting it to null 99% of the time.)  JLabel works too.